# How do I get the vertical position of an image in Javascript? (in relation to the document)

Tags: javascript, html, position

I am trying to dynamically get the Y position of an image in JavaScript in relation to the screen/document.
How can I do that? is there anything like in AC3 where you can do:
`getProperty(obj, _x)`?

Answer (score 3):

Replace your image `id` to get `y` or `top` position of image:

**JS:**

```
var offsets = document.getElementById('image_id').getBoundingClientRect();
                                 //HERE^
var top = offsets.top;
```

**Jquery:** If you use jquery library, do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var position = $("#image_id").position();
    var top = position.top;
});
```

Comment: Did you use `jquery` in your source?

Answer (score 0):

[`element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect) will return an object with values for the top, bottom, left, and right sides of the element.

To get the y position of an element, just do `element.getBoundingClientRect().top`.